# Unable to use LAG function

Tags: sql, oracle, lag

I need to update a table as :

```
ID | START_DATE | response| FINAL_TREND

1    14-10-2021     4                       
1    15-10-2021     3                       
1    16-10-2021     2                       
1    17-10-2021     2                        
1    18-10-2021     3
1    19-10-2021     2
```

OUTPUT AS:

```
ID | START_DATE | response| FINAL_TREND

1    14-10-2021     4           NULL            
1    15-10-2021     3            4           
1    16-10-2021     2            3           
1    17-10-2021     2            2            
1    18-10-2021     3            2
1    19-10-2021     2            3
```

So, when running a code:

```
SELECT LAG(RESPONSE,1) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE) AS NEW
FROM DUMMY_YC
```

Output as:

```
NULL
4
3
2
3
2
2
```

But when using same code in update AS:

```
UPDATE DUMMY_YC A SET A.RESPONSE = (SELECT LAG(B.RESPONSE,1) OVER (ORDER BY B.START_DATE) AS NEW
FROM DUMMY_YC B WHERE B.START_DATE=A.START_DATE)
```

output as:

```
7 rows updated.
```

But the actual updated value is

```
RESPONSE|

(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
```

Helps will be appreciated. Working On Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with `merge`.

Before:

```
SQL>   SELECT *
  2      FROM test
  3  ORDER BY id, start_date;

        ID START_DATE   RESPONSE FINAL_TREND
---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
         1 14.10.2021          4           0
         1 15.10.2021          3           0
         1 16.10.2021          2           0
         1 17.10.2021          2           0
         1 18.10.2021          3           0
         1 19.10.2021          2           0

6 rows selected.
```

Merge:

```
SQL> MERGE INTO test a
  2       USING (SELECT b.id,
  3                     b.start_date,
  4                     b.response,
  5                     LAG (b.response, 1) OVER (ORDER BY b.start_date) AS final_trend
  6                FROM test b) x
  7          ON (    x.id = a.id
  8              AND x.start_date = a.start_date)
  9  WHEN MATCHED
 10  THEN
 11     UPDATE SET a.final_trend = x.final_trend;

6 rows merged.
```

After:

```
SQL>   SELECT *
  2      FROM test
  3  ORDER BY id, start_date;

        ID START_DATE   RESPONSE FINAL_TREND
---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
         1 14.10.2021          4
         1 15.10.2021          3           4
         1 16.10.2021          2           3
         1 17.10.2021          2           2
         1 18.10.2021          3           2
         1 19.10.2021          2           3

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi PrabhakarKumarJha, if @Littlefoot answer is working for you, don't forget to give him an upvote and accept his answer.